# Firebase Deploy with NextJS -- How to add a file to .firebase/ in webpack

Tags: firebase, next.js, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build, web-frameworks

I'm deploying a nextJS app using firebase experimental frameworks.

I find the build process to be very confusing.  Somehow when I execute `firebase deploy`
a container gets built in the google cloud platform.  This container has something to do with the code in .firebase//functions directory.

I'm using a custom image loader in my next.config.js  which references a file cloudinaryLoader.js

Is there anyway in firebase.json (or) webpack (or) package.json to specify that I need to copy this file into the functions directory?  I think that this folder becomes the root of the container that gets built in google cloud platform so that hopefully the file would then be available at /workspace/cloudinaryLoader.js

I need to fix this-- but I would also be interested if anyone has any experience hosting NextJS
applications in production?  We've found that the built in image optimizer makes the GCP hosted SSR functions extremely unresponsive--latency sometimes >40s for 10kb images and very slow container startups.

Comment: Have a look at this [firebase-frameworks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-frameworks) which might help you